# My Angular class rendering using CSS is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My angular class rendering using css is not working, kindly check the code below and let me know why the div is still visible in the UI.

on the home service component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Renderer2, ElementRef, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'
import {Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router'

@Component ({
  selector: 'app-home-service',
  templateUrl: './home-service.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-service.component.css']
})
export class HomeServiceComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor (private router: Router, private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        const myElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(". service-btn")
        console.log(myElement)
        if (event.url === '/Services') {
          console.log(myElement)
          this.renderer.addClass(myElement, 'services-page')
        } else {
          console.log(myElement)
          this.renderer.removeClass(myElement, 'services-page')
        }
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
      }
    });
  }
}
```

in the home-service.component.html:

```
<div class="btn-box service-btn">
          <nav>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/Services" routerLinkActive="active">Read More</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

in the service.component.html: where it is rendered:
`<app-home-service></app-home-service>`

in the styles.css:

```
services-page {
  display: none! important
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console ? Also why don't you use the `ngClass` directive ?

Comment: I have no error in the console, I tried using ngClass (*ngIf="showHead) and ng-container, but it didn't work. so i resorted to the  CSS method.

infact the console.log is displaying correctly, but the UI is not affected.

Comment: do you also have the space `". service-btn"` in the selector in your code or is it just a typo here ?

Comment: Could you update your question to include what you try to accomplish? Why do you want to hide the button when navigating to `/Services`? What component is used for the `\Services` route? I think I can come up with a better solution if you let me know what your final goal is.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was able to use this on .ts file
 ```  ngOnInit() {
    // Get the current route's path
    const currentRoute = this.router.url;
    // Check if the current route is the service page
    this.isServices = currentRoute === '/Services'; // Adjust the route path as needed
  } ```
and
``` *ngIf="!isServices ``` inside the div

 to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

#### The short answer:

You missed a dot for the css class. It should be:

```css
.service-page {
 display: none;
}
```

There also should be no space before the `. service-btn`.

Comment: error in my typing here, there's a dot for the css class, Problem still persist.